# delete a record from grid and database on button click event in ext js

Tags: extjs, extjs3

i am using ext js designer with ruby on rails.
i want to delete a record from my grid and database on button click event.
can anyone help me?
thanks...

following is the code of my grid.

```
            xtype: 'grid',
            title: 'Products',
            store: 'productMaster',
            height: 176,
            id:'mygrid',
            name:'mygrid',
            sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({
                    singleSelect: true,
                    listeners: {
                           rowselect: function(sm, row, rec) {
                           Ext.getCmp("myform").getForm().loadRecord(rec);
                                                              }
                           }
                    }),
            columns: [
                {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    dataIndex: 'name',
                    header: 'name',
                    sortable: true,
                    width: 100
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    dataIndex: 'price',
                    header: 'price',
                    sortable: true,
                    width: 100
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    dataIndex: 'category',
                    header: 'category',
                    sortable: true,
                    width: 100
                },
```

and following is my code of delete button

```
             bbar: {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                height: 30,
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Delete',
                        width: 100,
                        height: 30,
                        id:'btnDelete',
                        handler: function() {

                                //alert('trying to delete the record...');
                                var store = Ext.getCmp("mygrid").getStore();
                                store.removeAt(store.getCount()-1);
                            }
```

due to this handler function the last record id deleted but it is deleted from the store not fro the database.i want the record to be deleted from the database also...

thanks...

Comment: You should include the source code of your grid in the question.

Comment: Do you have a writer set up for your store?  It should handle view, create, update, and delete appropriately when calling save on the store if configured correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Before we start: I noticed the configuration object for your grid has

```
xtype:'grid'
```

This, by itself, forbids any editing capability and server interactions (besides reading the store), because you are instancing an **Ext.grid.GridPanel**, while (I think) you need an **Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel**. For all of the following to run properly, you should change this line to:

```
xtype:'editorgrid'
```

First thing I would check is that the store has an **id** configuration attribute, and it is a configured column of the store reader. If the store cannot identify the record, it will think that the record does not exist, and will not generate a request to the server.

Second thing to check: has your store been configured to generate server requests? That is, is there a line like this in your store config object?

```
proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
    api:{
        read:'readscript.url',
        create:'insertscript.url',
        update:'updatescript.url',
        destroy:'deletescript.url'
    }
})
```

Next, have you defined the "**writer**" attribute in your store configuration object?
The store config object should have a **proxy** and a **writer** attribute to generate proper server requests upon deletion.

To specify a writer for the store you may simply write (for a common Json writer):

```
writer: new Ext.data.JsonWriter()
```

and the store will send all the appropriate write requests to the server.

Another painful (not well documented, I think) issue could be the presence of mandatory fields in the store reader. All columns are mandatory by default; to mark a column as "non-mandatory" you must specify (in the store reader column array):

```
{name:'column_name', allowBlank:true, /* other stuff like 'type' etc. */ }
```

Probably, when you add a new record to the grid, not all of the columns will be populated.
 The store will not generate a server create request until all mandatory columns are populated. Then, if you delete an unsaved record, the store will not generate the destroy request because it will assume that the record "does not exist".

Comment: thanks a lot.but the "proxy" element of grid gives me some error.but i have solved this by using a small ajax code. var g1 =Ext.getCmp('mygrid');
                    var dataid= g1.getSelectionModel().getSelected().id;
                     Ext.Ajax.request({
                     url: '/products/'+dataid,
                     method: 'DELETE',
                params: {'data[id]':dataid}
                  });